# how to substitute expressions in VIM

Tags: regex, vim

I want to substitute searched expression in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim).

For example:

I'm searching with an expression of : `/0x....` --> it will search for all strings in format
`0x0001`, `0x0002`, `0x1234`, etc.

Now, I want to replace the above search item with something like `0x0001_mystring`, `0x0002_mystring`, `0x1234_mystring` and so on.

Comment: That's very basic. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: Thanks @IngoKarkat i tried getting **:help** but i got lost and got confused.

Comment: Try `:vimtutor`, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following ex command:

```
:%s/0x\x*/&_mystring/g
```

- `\x` matches hexdigit character. equivalent to `[0-9A-Fa-f]`.
- `&` is replaced with the whole matched pattern.

Reference: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\x (Sorry, SO does not like `\` in URL)

Comment: I would add /g at the end, because he is looking for all strings in this format.

Comment: @EarlOfEgo, Thank you for pointing that. I fixed it according to you.

Comment: You can use the `\x` atom instead of `[0-9A-Fa-f]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitute command:

```
:%s/0x..../&_mystring/g
```

The syntax is similar to [sed](/questions/tagged/sed).

`%s` will search the whole document, use `:s/...` if you only want to search and replace in the line where your cursor is, use `:5,10s/...` if you want to search and replace in lines 5 to 10.

`0x....` is the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to search.

`&_mystring` replaces the search pattern with itself (`&`) and adds `_mystring`.

The flag `g` tells vim to do that for every occurrence on a specific line, otherwise it substitutes only the first occurrence on every line.

Comment: This only works if every hex number has four digits exactly.

Comment: ...which was exactly what the OP asked for. No need to downvote.